# Java networking - Look for packets without blocking the thread?

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm creating a Networking Utilities package, to make it easier to create network applications, like chat applications, games etc. I wonder if it's possible to, in the server thread, look for packets all the time, without blocking the thread?

I want to do this, because, for example, when I'm going to create a multiplayer server, I don't want the whole server to be blocked and unplayable because the server is looking for packets that tells the server that someone is connecting.

What's the best way of solving this?

To put the joining detection in a separate thread?
Also; how many threads can you run in a single application? Should you try to hold the amount of threads down as much as possible? Is 4 threads too much?

Comment: You should have an accepting thread and a thread per connection. When you get to 10,000 threads is the time to worry about it. Maybe.

Comment: So it's recommended to have one thread for listening for join requests?

Comment: What I said. It's recommended to have one thread per socket. Maybe even two: one for reading, one for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I put the join detection in a separate thread and class. Then, while the join detector  was active, it checked for packets and added them to a list of requests. Then, from the server class, every update, i checked if there was any gathered requests in the join detection class.

Sorry for the wrong answer before.

Comment: Fixed what exactly? Fixed your question about not blocking the thread?